# Field name for customer name in Squarebit Charge for Stripe

Tags: plugins, plugin-charge

I am using the Charge plugin and am not able to pass the customer name to Stripe. The form field name I am using is "customerName" and I have successfully done this in the past - it shows up in the Craft CP, but not in the Stripe account.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As I indicated in the original post, I have successfully used "customerName" as the field name for the customer. After contacting Stripe Support (pretty awesome, BTW), they tell me the correct field name is "name" and much better to use the parameter stripe-data="name". That did the trick.

Comment: @roiagenta do you know how to make the customerName a required field?

Comment: You can just add 'required' to the input - only supported on HTML5, but works like a charm! <input type="text name="customerName" required> Note there are no quotes around the required parameter